# C++: Finding second max element in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new here and learning C++ language. Right now I have to find the second largest element in the array but my code is not giving me correct output sometimes. I have the following code to find the second max element.

```
for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
{
    if(arr[i] > max)
    {
        second_max = max;
        max = arr[i];
    }
}
```

This code works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't give the correct value of second max element. Please help me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: The code is a bit unclear, what are you setting the variable "max" to in the first place?

Comment: We don't know how you initialize `max` or `second_max`. That's (likely) the problem.

Comment: You should add a constraint to keep the solution O(N) otherwise you will get solutions that just sort the array which is quicker to type but slower

Comment: What do you mean by `second_max` (in case of tie)? for `{5, 5, 4}`, do you want `5` or `4`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you are finding `maximum` and the `second_maximum` elements, what I noticed is that you are skipping the scenario when the `arr[i]` is greater than the `second_max` but less than the `max` e.g. for the following scenario your code will not work fine

```
max: 15

second_max = 7

arr[i] = 12
```

add the following condition to your code below the first `if` condition:

```
else if(arr[i] > second_max)
{
    second_max = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Although this will work, I think the solution with sort is much more robust.  It is *obviously* correct (and the extension to "third largest" etc is very obvious).  Sort will be slower for large inputs of course.

Comment: this should be `else if` since if it is `>max` it will be `>second max` and you will set both to `arr[i]` unless there is an `else`.   Also @MartinBonner , sorting is overkill, a linear solution can also be proven to be correct.

Comment: if `arr[i]=20` then `arr[i]>max` so `second_max = 15; max =20` then `arr[i]>second max` so `second_max` will also be set to 20.  The `else` prevents this.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using only standard algorithms:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

int second_max(std::vector<int> v)
{
    using namespace std;

    sort(begin(v),
         end(v),
         std::greater<>());

    auto last = unique(begin(v),
                       end(v));

    auto size = last - begin(v);

    return (size == 0)
    ? 0
    : (size == 1)
    ? v[0]
    : v[1];
}


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << second_max({ 3,5,7,7,2,4,3,2,6 }) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could also use [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

Comment: @LogicStuff I don't see that requirement in the standard, or on the cppreference page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique

Comment: @LogicStuff: It doesn't require a sorted range. Sometimes you just want to remove _consecutive_ duplicates instead of _all_ duplicates.

Comment: Wrongly phrased... I think you need to remove all the duplicates of the greatest element to get the correct `nth_element`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than `std::sort` this should normally be done with [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element). It's exactly the scenario for it was designed and avoids sorting the entire collection when you only care about a couple of elements.

Comment: Even better, it performs the partial sort for you, so `std::nth_element` can combine with `std::sort` to act as an `nlargest` (analogous to [Python's `heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)); you can get the X largest (for any X in order) with work that's linear in the length of the input and only `O(n log n)` in the number of max elements needed: `std::nth_element(std::begin(vals), std::begin(vals)+(nummax - 1), std::end(vals), std::greater<>()); followed by a `std::sort` of only the first `nummax` elems. This is the best answer for production code.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: If thats what you want, you can just use [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort). No ned to manually combine `std::nth_element` with `std::sort`

Comment: @MikeMB: you can use partial_sort, but using it to find largest elements isn't trivial either--it's not immediately obvious (at least to me) that it's a huge improvement. In any case we're getting quite a ways from the original question. In any case we're getting quite a ways away from the original question.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Never said that it is a **huge** improvement, but it is one line (or 50%) less typing and is probably (I don't know about the implementation) more efficient.

Comment: @MikeMB: It's unlikely to be any more efficient (I have looked at implementations). Unlikely to be substantially shorter either by the time you use reverse iterators and std::greater to get largest items at top where you want them.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: you lost me there - if I wanted the N largest values in sorted order, I would write `partial_sort(begin(vals),begin(vals)+N,end(vals),greater<>()`. Which IMHO is  shorter than `nth_element(begin(vals), begin(vals)+N - 1,end(vals), greater<>()); sort(begin(vals), begin(vals)+N - 1,greater<>())` - more so if we go for a sorting criteria for which you'd write a lambda.

Comment: Also, for some reason, `nth_element` seems to perform much worse than `partial_sort` on my machine, but that might be a glitch in VS2015 or a bug in my benchmark - I have to investigate, when I've time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little program. I'm using only std's standard algorithms and it's the simplest I can think of.

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> ar = {1, 5, 15, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 14};

    // Sort the array
    std::sort(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar));

    // Print the second max element
    std::cout << ar[ar.size() - 2];
}
```

Comment: it's not enough generic: whats happen if arr.size() is less then 2 ?

Comment: Well, if arr.size() is less than 2, you don't need std to find the second max! wrote this example having in mind he will have a static array of elements not a vector.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your if-statement is incomplete. Here is the working version:

```
  for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
  {
    if(max < arr[i]) {
      second_max = max;
      max = arr[i];
    }
    else if(second_max < arr[i])
      second_max = arr[i];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

/**
 * get second max of array
 * @param arr the Array
 * @param len the array length
 * @return return second max if searched otherwise return -1
 */
int getSecondMax(const int *arr, int len) {
    int secondMax = INT_MIN; //-2147483647 - 1
    int max = INT_MIN + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            secondMax = max;
            max = arr[i];
        } else if (arr[i] > secondMax && arr[i] != max) {
            secondMax = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return secondMax != INT_MIN + 1 ? secondMax : -1;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {0, 3, -1, 4, 5};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    int secondMax = getSecondMax(arr, len);
    secondMax != -1 ? printf("the second max = %d\n", secondMax) : printf("not found second max\n");
    return 0;
}
```